# Passing data from C# to Python using PythonNet

Tags: python, c#, python.net

My question is how to pass a C# dictionary (Dictionary<string, dynamic[]>()) to Python. and then I want to transform the dict in python into a polars DataFrame and do some random operation on it.

My code looks something like this :

**C# ConsoleApp Code :**

```
using Python.Runtime;

var forPolars = new Dictionary<string, dynamic[]>(){
    {"stringCol", new dynamic[] {"string1", "string2", "string3" } },
    {"numberCol", new dynamic[] {10.5, 1567, 25.55874456 }},
    {"dateCol", new dynamic[] {new DateTime(2015, 12, 25), new DateTime(2015, 02, 03), new DateTime(2015, 01, 15) }}
};

Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\~\Python-3.11\python311.dll";
PythonEngine.Initialize();

using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
    sys.path.append(@"C:\Users\~\PythonScripts");
    dynamic pythonScript = Py.Import(scriptName);

    try
    {
        pythonScript.InvokeMethod("polars_test", new PyObject[] { forPolars.ToPython() }); 

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Python Code :**

```
import polars as pl 

def polars_test(dict):
    print(dict)
    df = pl.DataFrame(dict)
    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)
```